# barrier() function issue in Vulkan tessellation control shader on integrated videocard

Tags: glsl, vulkan, tessellation

I found out that running tessellation control shader which contains `barrier()` call on my integrated Intel videocard yields no geometry (????)

So just for example, the following simple shader works well on my dedicated Nvidia card, but doesn't work with Intel:

```
#version 450 core

layout (vertices = 4) out;

void main() {
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
    gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelInner[1] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[3] = 1;
    barrier();
}
```

However, the same code without `barrier()` call works on Intel card too.

Would be grateful if someone could guess, where to look for the cause of the problem

**UPDATE**

Found out that when `barrier()` is called before `gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;` everything works fine, so I just need to move this statement to the end:

```
#version 450 core

layout (vertices = 4) out;

void main() {
    gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelInner[1] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[3] = 1;
    barrier();
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

This behavior is still not clear for me, so would be cool if someone could explain it to me, why I shouldn't write to `gl_out` before `barrier()`

Comment: Um... what's the point of that `barrier` call?

Comment: @NicolBolas: this is just the most simple example which reproduces the problem, there is no point in `barrier` call, but this example shows that exactly `barrier` causes this strange artifact. Originally I was computing outer levels and then calling barrier to make them visible to all invokations to compute inner levels as average of corresponding outer levels.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a graphics driver or hardware bug to me - there is nothing wrong with what you are doing from a specification point of view.